# In Android, while switching between the screens the GPS data is lost

Tags: android

I have three activities, Activity1, Activity2, and Activity3.. Activity1 is the main activity from which am switching to other two activities. While I switch to Activity2 from main activity it starts properly, when I switch to Activity3 from main activity and come back to the Activity2 all previous data will be lost and it starts from starting.

Is there any other way to switch to the activities other than using the startActivity() method.

Comment: What is the data that your are trying to access in the Activity? You should use save all the data that you wantbefore switching to another Actiity, or it will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in static variable in another class and can call these whenever required.. i think it will work

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you seem to need to pass information between Activities.
You should use a `Bundle` to pass information from Activities 1 to 3 to 2,
Or use `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` if you're going from Activities 1 to 3 to 1 to 2.

Try this, hope it helps.

Sender.java:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Receiver.class);
    i.putExtra("object_name", object);
    startActivity(i);
```

Receiver.java:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    Type _variable = extras.getTypeExtra("object_name");
```

Do note that `getTypeExtra(...)` requires you to specify the type of information you are about to retrieve.
ex. `getStringExtra(...), getFloatExtra(...)`

Comment: Check out more about Intents and Bundles here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html